# English to Greek Dictionary

Tags: windows, dictionary

I need a free English to Greek Dictionary for Windows. I won't be able to have internet access for some time, so I would like to have a dictionary on my laptop.

What I need:

- Index
- Phrases
- Search
- Examples, Synonyms, Antonyms (would be good, but not necessarily)

Comment: Do you want a free or a paid option?